# XIB window in mac app is auto resized?

Tags: macos, storyboard

I am new to mac dev , i have an `.xib` `window` which is long. There are many `textViews` along its main `window` from the top the the bottom .

I can see all of them on `storyboard` , and it looks ok, but when i run the program, the `window` is smaller , and i only see half of it, hence can't see the text on the bottom .

How do i fix this ? ( i couldn't just enlarge the window when the app is running )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the Window selected in Interface Builder, you can simply set its initial size:

[image]